# After Effects: Quick way to go from one text layer to another?

Tags: adobe, after-effects

In after effects if I want to make a sentence into different words I will have to continually write a new text layer.

But I can't figure out how to quickly deslect the current text layer and move to the next one?

Can you advise please.

Essentially this is the current process I'm using and it's long and boring.

Click text tool.
Click on area.
Write word.
Click on pointer (top left)
Click back to text tool
Click on area.
Repeat until I've made all the text layers.

Really annoying and I can't find anything on Google :-(

Comment: One for superuser.com perhaps? This forum is for programming, not advanced *users* of software - which this question is about.

Comment: Went there and asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

on a macbook press fn Enter, reposition your cursor and then your good to go.